# Is there any way to make this a faster algorithm?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, big-o

If I understand Big O Notation, and believe me my understanding at this point is probably much lower than most, <strike>the following line of code is *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*</strike> per the comment by Keyser this is in fact already an *O(n)* operation:

```
"Hello, World!".ToLower().Contains("a");
```

because `ToLower()` is an `O(n)` operation and `Contains` is as well. Maybe it's `O(n + n)`, again, my understanding is still fuzzy.

**NOTE:** below is a listing of test methods that were run in a `Release` build, and leverage the `Stopwatch` class to track run time.

However, **I'd like to make it faster**, and so consider these three test methods:

```
private static void TestToLower(int i)
{
    var s = "".PadRight(i, 'A');

    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    s.ToLower().Contains('b');
    sw.Stop();

    _tests.Add(string.Format("ToLower{0}", i), sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

private static void TestHashSet(int i)
{
    var s = "".PadRight(i, 'A');

    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var lookup = new HashSet<char>(s.ToLower().AsEnumerable());
    lookup.Contains('b');
    sw.Stop();

    _tests.Add(string.Format("ToHashSet{0}", i), sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

private static void TestHashSet2(int i)
{
    var s = "".PadRight(i, 'A');

    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var lookup = new HashSet<char>(s.ToLower().ToArray());
    lookup.Contains('b');
    sw.Stop();

    _tests.Add(string.Format("ToHashSet2{0}", i), sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Now consider executing those like this:

```
TestToLower(1000000);
TestToLower(2000000);
TestToLower(4000000);

TestHashSet(1000000);
TestHashSet(2000000);
TestHashSet(4000000);

TestHashSet2(1000000);
TestHashSet2(2000000);
TestHashSet2(4000000);
```

the results are as follows:

```
ToLower1000000: 22.00 ms
ToLower2000000: 40.00 ms
ToLower4000000: 84.00 ms
ToHashSet1000000: 48.00 ms
ToHashSet2000000: 73.00 ms
ToHashSet4000000: 145.00 ms
ToHashSet21000000: 58.00 ms
ToHashSet22000000: 107.00 ms
ToHashSet24000000: 219.00 ms
```

Each of them clearly has to use the `ToLower` method still, but I'm attempting to use the `HashSet` to make the lookup faster. Ideally you wouldn't have to scan the entire string. Further, I really thought the second overall test, `TestHashSet`, would be faster because it doesn't have to create significant chunks of memory to allocate the `HashSet`.

In retrospect I see why the last two methods are slower, I think. I believe they are slower because I've got the same algorithm as the first (i.e. I have to go through the entire string twice at a minimum) but then on top of that I'm doing the lookup after that.

How can I make this algorithm faster? We use this a lot, where we have to compare strings regardless of case.

Comment: To do two independent `O(n)` operations in a row is indeed `O(n+n)` which is `O(n)`. The thought process is something like this: _Does the number of iterations increase with respect to `n` or `n^2`?_

Comment: @Keyser, so the only faster operation would be `log(n)`? And if so, what in the world does `log` mean then, because I clearly didn't understand that `n+n` is `n`.

Comment: Big O "math" states that O(n+n) is equivalent to O(n)

Comment: @TheSolution I suggest reading an introduction to algorithmic complexity measures. n+n is not n, but O(n+n) is the same as O(n).

Comment: @Keyser It doesn't need to have a base of 2.  it can have any base.

Comment: For starters, make sure your benchmark reflects your use case. Do you really only search once per "haystack" string, and are your strings really huge (in the order of millions of bytes)? If you search multiple times, change your benchmark to account for that (by re-using any data structures you build from the string). If your strings are smaller, shrink your tests strings to get closer to the real deal (time multiple runs as one if it ends up going too fast).

Comment: log_2(n) = log_10(n)/log_10(2). Multiplication by a constant, such as 1/log_10(2) does not affect the complexity.

Comment: @Keyser Sure it would.  Look at a B tree for example.  Its lookup time is a log with a base of the number of items per node, which is frequently 256.  Log base 256 is a heck of a lot different (and faster) than a log base two.

Comment: @Keyser Well, it's any constant base, if you want to be specific.  A base involving N would indeed need to be a different category.

Comment: As to the OP's specific problem, if the number of strings you are searching on is small, or you are frequently performing the same operation on the same strings, you can leverage caching or precomputing of values to reduce the complexity to O(1).

Comment: @Servy, it's funny you mention caching and such. That's a common go to for me. But as I started getting around peers talking about Big O, I felt that I may have been just spreading out the problem rather than solving it because they're always talking about making it faster and never about caching and stuff. Maybe my example is just a bad example for making this now a *`log(n)`* operation?

Comment: @TheSolution If your input string is sorted you can perform the search in log(n) time ;)  In general though, understanding how to apply big O to very simple operations, such as this, and analyzing how different changes affect it is how you learn to quickly and properly apply big O, allowing you to use it to analyze more complex operations in the future.

Comment: @TheSolution good luck speeding this up. I'd recommend some reading on Big O notation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: Why do you need to make this faster?  What is the actual problem?  Really, do you have users complaining about 22 ms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No offense intended, but you don't understand big-O.  O(n + n) is the same as O(n).  The whole point of big-O is to "hide" constant factors.  You can't do better than O(n) with one processor on this problem.  You might get O(n/k) on k cores by splitting the string into k pieces and searching them with separate threads.

Converting a character to lower case is a constant time operation. Checking for a match with a desired character is a cheap constant time operation. Inserting a character in a hash set is a fairly expensive constant time operation.  In your hash set tests, you have added this rather large constant cost to the handling of each character.  Since it is larger than the constant cost of merely looking at the character to see if it matches the pattern string,  your run times get longer.

Using a hash set for lookup makes sense only if you're looking up many values.  If you need to do multiple lookups *on the same string* to see if it contains a any or all of k different characters, then you will probably benefit by building the hash set because k lookups will take O(k) time rather than the O(kn) time to scan the whole string for each character.

If you are looking for only one character in each string, forget big-O.  Constant factors are your best hope.   You should consider a low-level loop.  It would go something like this:

```
static bool findChar(string str, char charToFind) {
  char upper = Char.toUpper(charToFind);
  char lower = Char.toLower(charToFind);
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == upper || str[i] == lower) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Sorry in advance for syntax problems.  I'm not a C# programmer.  Note this scans the string *at most* once.  If the character is found early, it stops.  The *expected number* of characters checked is half those in the string.  This function also generates no garbage.

On the other hand the expected number of characters touched by

```
str.ToLower().Contains("a");
```

is 1.5 times the length of `str`, and garbage will be generated.  So you might win with the explicit loop

If this is still too slow, a native function might produce a small gain. You'd have to try it to find out.

Comment: +1.  Of course, it would have been helpful if OP had given common use cases (How long is `s`?  Are you looking for a substring or a character?  How often do you expect to find it?).

Answer (score 1):

I believe your code is **O(2n) = O(n)**. That's because each call traverses the input string 2 times. To reduce the algorithmic bound on your running time, you would need an algorithm that has a logarithmic bound, or **O(n^k), with k<1** algorithm, which I believe is impossible in your scenario. The best I can suggest is to utilize invariant specific information: for example, if you know that your strings always have the first letter in uppercase, only change the first character in the string. This is an example of how you could exploit domain-specific knowledge.

Comment: “To reduce the algorithmic bound on your running time, you would need a O(log n) algorithm” doesn't make sense.  Any algorithm with complexity lower than O(n) will reduce the algorithmic bound.  Of course O(0) is best, and any of  O(1), O(log* n), O(log log n), O(sqrt n), O(n^⅔), etc., would reduce the bound.

Comment: @jwpat7 O(0) == O(1).  And O(log(n) * n) > O(n), not less than.  Other than that, yes.

Comment: @Servy, O(1) = set of functions bounded by a constant. O(0) = set that contains the constant function 0. They are not the same.

Comment: @Joni 1 != 0, but O(1) == O(0), for the same reason that n + 1 != n but O(n + 1) == O(n).  Two big O functions are considered equivalent if there execution time differs by a constant value.

Comment: @Servy, `log* n` denotes the *[Iterated Logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm)* function and has nothing to do with `n log n`.  Also, if “O(1) == O(0)” then every O(1) function would be O(0), which isn't so; see the [big O definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition).  There is no positive real number M such that c ≤ M·0, (where c represents the time taken by any particular O(1) function).  You might think of O(0) as code that is compiled away and never executes, and O(1) as a basic block that gets executed.